# QEMU PCIe TLP Emulation

Tags: qemu, kvm, pci-e

Does QEMU emulate the PCIe Transaction Layer somehow?

When I have a virtual Switch like (https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/a-study-of-the-linux-kernel-pci-subsystem-with-qemu) am I able to intercept at least the TLP's going over it? Or is the abstraction so high the the hypervisor does not go down to that layer at all.

Comment: I already took a look at the QEMU source code and it seems the the answer is no. However, I might have overlooked something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected QEMU does not implement the TLP layer at the moment. Instead whenever a memory access happens qemu jumps out of the KVM execution and handles MMIO.