# MCHBAR Base Address Register (MCHBAR_0_0_0_PCI) — Offset 48h

Tags: intel, energy, msr

I'm trying to access the Secondary Plane Energy Status
(SECP_NRG_STTS_0_0_0_MCHBAR_PCU register.
The Intel documentation (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/743846/13th-generation-intel-core-processors-datasheet-volume-2-of-2.html)
denotes an offset of MCHBAR + 592Ch for this.

What is the MCHBAR address? - or how do i determine it?

Note: I'm running a Linux OS, and this is for a project related to energy consumption. Intel support has not been very helpful on this question.
Low-level machine programming is not really my expertise, so I apologize, if my question is trivial or ignorant in any way.

I have read other documentation that suggests specific MSRs for reading RAPL energy status counters, but some of the values I get (specifically) PP1, does not seem correct at all. On asking Intel for help, they provided the above mentioned documentation(see link). I cannot make sense of it though.

Comment: Is that a PCIe MMIO register?  In PCI terminology, each device has a BAR.  [What is the Base Address Register (BAR) in PCIe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30190050) .  "MCH" might be "Memory Controller Hub" aka northbridge which is actually part of the CPU SoC on Intel since Nehalem.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)).  So you're probably looking for an `lspci` entry like `00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)`.  (You *could* even hard-code a number from `lspci -vv` for initial testing.)